# K-mean clustering, make centroids not overlap nodes

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have done K-mean++ clustering and obtained the centroids of the clusters, using Python 2.7, following the method given in http://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/improved-seeding-for-clustering-with-k-means/

In my problem, there is a further constraint that the distances between any centroid to any node should be larger than a constant. What is the best way to achieve?

It is possible that one centroid is too close to several nodes.

Any suggestions on how to displace the centroids a bit?

Many thanks.

For example, the nodes to be clustered are 
MyNodes = [[469500, 5802610], [468764, 5803422], [467991, 5804202], [470260, 5799949], [469486, 5800730], [468713, 5801510], [467939, 5802291], [467166, 5803072], [467966, 5800204], [467193, 5800985], [466420, 5801766], [466457, 5799700], [465678, 5800488], [464950, 5799229], [470615, 5796600], [469842, 5797405], [470320, 5794955], [469547, 5795735], [468773, 5796516], [467990, 5797297], [470062, 5793215], [469289, 5793996], [468515, 5794776], [467742, 5795557], [466969, 5796338], [466195, 5797119], [469976, 5791334], [469202, 5792115], [468429, 5792896], [467656, 5793676], [466882, 5794457], [466109, 5795238], [465336, 5796050], [464600, 5796840], [470160, 5789250], [469354, 5789972], [468581, 5790753], [467808, 5791534], [467034, 5792315], [466261, 5793096], [465488, 5793877], [464714, 5794658], [463941, 5795499], [463150, 5796210], [469500, 5787920], [468698, 5788614], [467925, 5789395], [467152, 5790176]]

Centroids = [[  467839.6,  5793224.1], [  467617.22222222,  5800489.94444444]]
Centroid[0] would be too close to node[29], Centroid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdaMj.png) would be too close to node[8].[image]

[image]

Comment: You say that centroid should not be closer to a node than a constant, what is this constant in your case? Also, if the constant is large enough, the solution might not be possible, or even if it is possible the location of "centroids" could be such that they are no longer anything like true centroids.

Comment: In the example, the constant is 500.

Comment: I do admit that it might be impossible to get true centroids (as shown in the picture, when the red centroid sits in the R 500 circles of three nodes), but I think there should be an optimised method to make the pseudo centroids as close as possible to the true centroids, and minimize the amount of constraint violation

Comment: What is the incentive behind this? Frankly, my guess would be that you misunderstood something. Maybe the distance of the centroid to any _other centroid_ has to be larger that that constant?

Comment: I mean the distance from centroid to node should be less than a constant. Usually a centroid will not overlap another centroid, or be too close to another centroid. If two centroids are too close, we might just need to merge these two corresponding clusters.

Comment: At the moment your problem does not seem very well defined, and it seems quite hard. It might be helpful if you tell us your ultimate goal because there might be an easier solution. What is the problem with a centroid being to close to a node?

Comment: "I mean the distance from centroid to node should be **less** than a constant." That seems to make more sense, but is contrary to what's written in the question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Maybe I just need to displace the centroid node to the closet intersecting point of the three circles

Comment: the distances between any centroid to any node should be LARGER than a constant (they cannot be too close)

Comment: But if you move the centroid to an intersection, you will get closer to one node.

Comment: to the intersecting points marked by cross, the closet is the red cross one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and I am not at all sure whether I do, then the solution is already apparent from your drawings:

You want the point that is closest  to a given centroid point; and has a minimum distance from a set of node points.

- Draw a circle around each node point, with your minimum distance as the radius
- Intersect each circle with each other circle, note the intersection points
- discard any intersection point that is closer than the minimum distance to a node point.
- from the remaining intersection points, take the one closest to the centroid point. That is your new displaced centroid.

Runtime for the naive implementation should be `O(number_of_nodes^2)`, though you can optimize that by using some fast nearest-neighbour lookup data structure, such as a kd-tree, when you intersect the circles and discard the intersection points that are too close.

This should be the optimal solution; no matter which algorithm you use, you cannot find a point closer to the original centroid that fits the minimum distance constraint; and this algorithm should always find that optimal point.

Though since the centroid is generally surrounded by node points, the new point may be quite some distance away if the node points are densely packed.

Comment: Yes, I just found the solution after posting the question. Thank you for your reply all the same.

Comment: Would you mind to unveal the practical case behind this additional constraint or a slightly generalized version of it ?